# How to get EditTextPreference reference in main activity android

Tags: android, reference, preferences, edittextpreference

How can I get a reference to my EditTextPreference in my main activity?

I have tried this:

```
EditTextPreference mEditTextPref =(EditTextPreference) findPreference(incrementby);
```

but its giving me this error;

```
incrementby cannot be resolved to a variable
```

This is the code for the EditTextPreference

```
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:key="incrementby"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:summary="Set the incremental value of the counter"
        android:title="Increase Count by" />
```

After getting a reference to the EditTextPreferece, what I want to do is, use this reference to set the value of the EditTextPreferece through my main activity. Something like;

```
mEditTextPref.setText("1");
```

Comment: is `mEditTextPref.setText("1");` giving null pointer exception?

Comment: nvm, I figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the error says it: it is not a variable!! that is, the 'icrementby' is not a variable and expected a string!  so enclose it in a double quotes ("incrementby").

```
EditTextPreference mEditTextPref =(EditTextPreference) findPreference("incrementby");
```

**EDIT**

create a local variable in your activity:

```
Context mContext;
```

and in the onCreate, do:

```
mContext=getBaseContext();
```

then use

```
EditTextPreference mEditTextPref =(EditTextPreference) mContext.findPreference("incrementby");
```

Comment: now it says The method findPreference(String) is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: I am trying to use it like this mEditTextPref.setText("1"); but its not working. It doesn't give any error but the app force closes.

Comment: what you are trying to do? am confused! here you are asking to set text, but in the above question i cant find such a statement or something!!

Comment: basically, I am trying to set the text of EditTextPreference in my Preference XML through my main class. So after getting the reference to the EditTextPreference, I want to change the text for it from my main class.

Comment: please try to ask questions with clarity, otherwise you will not get enough response/ans from here, I think you hve solved the above problem, then mark it as acepted, so that others coming here by searching with similar problem can find it as a solution! if I answer to something different from question will give them a wrong info.

Comment: It might be that my question didn't come out as expected but your answer weren't what I was looking for, sorry. I am going to edit my post.